# Selecting from Point column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, geometry

How to select from Point column data type(native) in PostgreSQL?

```
select a.* from indsolv.address As a where a.location = '93.2321, 21.0321'
```

Getting error for the above query!

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: point = unknown
LINE 1: ...ct a.* from indsolv.address As a where a.location = '93.2321...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 55
```

Comment: Cross-posted to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/252066/how-to-select-from-point-column-in-postgresql where there is an answer

Comment: Please clarify (and then decide on which board you want to post) if this is about the native PostgreSQL `POINT` type, or the PostGIS `GEOMETRY(POINT)` type!

Answer (score 3):

*You seem to be using the native PostgreSQL `POINT` type rather than the PostGIS `GEOMETRY(POINT)`; this answer is for the PostGIS extension! See the answer in the cross post on DBA.SE for the PostgreSQL native type.*

---

You will need to to construct an actual geometry from your input coordinates to compare against values in a `GEOMETRY` column, e.g.

- `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(93.2321, 21.0321))` or
- `'POINT(93.2321 21.0321)'::GEOMETRY(POINT, <SRID)`

---

**However:**

PostGIS stores geometry with standard IEEE floating point precision, and checking 4 decimal places against 15 leaves *plenty* of room for misalignment.

Thus, you'd also want to make sure you are comparing precision in the same order of magnitude; use e.g. `ST_Snap` or `ST_SnapToGrid` to make sure two points are considered equal even if they differ after the 4th decimal place

Finally, the recommended way to compare PostGIS geometries is `ST_Equals`.

```
SELECT *
FROM   indsolv.address
WHERE  ST_Equals(
         a.location,
         ST_Snap(
           a.location,
           ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(93.2321, 21.0321), <srid>),
           0.0001
         )
       )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer:
    SELECT a.* FROM indsolv.address a
    WHERE a.location ~= point '(93.2321, 21.0321)';

```
... WHERE a.location ~= point '93.2321, 21.0321';
... WHERE a.location ~= '93.2321, 21.0321'::point;
... WHERE a.location ~= '(93.2321, 21.0321)'::point;
... WHERE a.location ~= cast('93.2321, 21.0321' AS point);
... WHERE a.location ~= cast('(93.2321, 21.0321)' AS point);

... WHERE a.location ~= '(93.2321, 21.0321)';
... WHERE a.location ~= '93.2321, 21.0321';

... WHERE a.location ~= point('93.2321, 21.0321)';
... WHERE a.location ~= point('(93.2321, 21.0321)');
... WHERE a.location ~= point('93.2321', '21.0321');
```